# EAFP in Haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, option-type

I have a doubt of the Maybe and Either types, and their hypothetical relation to EAFP(Easier Ask Forgiveness to Permission). I've worked with Python and get used to work with the EAFP paradigm in the world of exceptions.

The classical example: Division by zero

```
def func(x,y):
    if not y:
        print "ERROR."
    else: return (x/y)
```

and Python's style:

```
def func(x,y):
    try:
        return (x/y)
    except: return None
```

In Haskell, the first function would be

```
func :: (Eq a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> a
func x y = if y==0 then error "ERROR." else x/y
```

and with Maybe:

```
func :: (Eq a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> Maybe a
func x y = if y==0 then Nothing else Just (x/y)
```

In Python's version, you run `func` *without* checking `y`. With Haskell, the story is the opposite: `y` is checked.

My question:

1. Formally, does Haskell support the EAFP paradigm or "prefers" LBYL although admits a semi-bizarre EAFP approximation?

PD: I called "semi-bizarre" because, even if it is intuitively readable, it looks (at least for me) like it vulnerates EAFP.

Comment: I've never seen "EAFP" or "LBYL" paradigms formally described, so I don't know how to answer whether Haskell supports them "formally". Haskell does support exceptions. Personally, I think "EAFP" is an anti-pattern.

Comment: You mean by the `error` function?

Comment: The `error` function is one example, yes.

Comment: I think you are asking for opinions here - the question is what is your expected behavior if `y = 0`? Because the two versions behave very differently - same with Python (I guess - I don't really know any Python)

Comment: @CarlosAlonsoGómez You should have a read through [*Maybe Haskell*](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/maybe-haskell-our-newest-book), an ebook that was recently released. It takes the `Maybe` type as a recurring example to explain some concepts central to Haskell, including how failures (absence of value) can be propagated and dealt with only at the "boundaries" of your program. It's a good read.

Comment: @CarstenKönig It is not an opinion question. I apologise if it appeared to be.

Comment: @Jubobs Maybe I'll take a look. I wonder if it explains something about the `Applicative` class, because I can't understand it.

Comment: @CarlosAlonsoGómez It does cover  the `Functor`-`Applicative`-`Monad` trio, and does a pretty good job at explaining how each is more powerful than the previous one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Haskell style with `Maybe` and `Either` forces you to check for the error at *some point*, but it does not have to be right away. If you don't want to deal with the error now, you can just propagate it on through the rest of your computation.

Taking your hypothetical safe divide-by-0 example, you could use it in a broader computation without an explicit check:

```
do result <- func a b
   let x = result * 10
   return x
```

Here, you don't have to match on the `Maybe` returned by `func`: you just extract it into the `result` variable using do-notation, which automatically propagates failure throughout. The consequence is that you don't need to deal with the potential error immediately, but the final result of the computation is wrapped in `Maybe` itself.

This means that you can easily combine (compose) functions that miht result in an error without having to check the error at each step.

In a sense, this gives you the best of both worlds. You still only have to check for errors in one place, at the very end, but you're **explicit** about it. You have to use something like do-notation to take care of the actual propagation and you can't ignore the final error by accident: if you don't want to handle it, you have to turn it into a runtime error explicitly.

Isn't explicit better than implicit?

Now, Haskell also has a system of exceptions for working with runtime errors that you do not have to check at all. This is useful occasionally, but not too often. In Haskell, we only use it for errors that we *do not* expect to ever catch—truly exceptional situations. The rule of thumb is that a runtime exception represents *a bug in your program*, while an improper input or merely an uncommon case should be represented with `Maybe` or `Either`.